# where do I add -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 (Pytorch)

Tags: linux, gcc, pytorch, archlinux

I am installing pytorch from the source, and am running into issues where it is using my current gcc compiler and not gcc-5

I have tried to google this problem for hours, searched stack and everything.

I have tried:

exporting the C and CXX variables to no avail 
linking the variable

I am using arch linux

Comment: Did you try editing the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/setup.py#L429) itself and replace with the desired compiler path?

Comment: kHarshit, okay adding CC and CXX paths to setup.py seemed to work thanks! but not it is spitting another error hmm